# Actionscript 3 - can't open multiple navigateToURL() instances at the same time

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, navigatetourl

I am new to AS3, I want to open multiple browser tabs with flash.

I'm trying to simply start multiple instances of navigateToURL().

```
for each (var str:String in arrayofrequests) 
{
[...]
    try { navigateToURL(request, "_blank");}
[...]
}
```

but only the last instance of navigateToURL gets executed in the browser.
I searched online and someone pointed out callLater could solve this issue.
But every time I try to use callLater I get

```
 Error: Call to a possibly undefined method callLater.
```

I analyzed adobe documentation here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7b06.html

> All objects that inherit from the UIComponent class can open the callLater() method.

How I do this? I tried to change my code to something like this

```
public class Main extends UIComponent
```

but it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, [UIComponent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html) class is the base class for all visual components used in Flex ( like [`Label`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Label.html), [`Progressbar`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/ProgressBar.html), ...), but I think that your are using Flash, so it's not the good way.

Really I don't know why you want to open many urls in the browser in the same time ( and I think that your final user may be will not like that ), but you have to use some intervals between every `navigateToURL()` calls using a [`Timer`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html) object for example :

```
var urls:Array = [
    'http://www.wikipedia.org',
    'http://www.ubuntu.com',
    'http://www.stackoverflow.com'
];

var timer:Timer = new Timer(300, urls.length);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
    function onTimer(e:TimerEvent):void {
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest(urls[timer.currentCount - 1]), '_blank');
    }
    timer.start();
```

Hope that can help.